# Ruby on Rails - undefined method `devise_for' or no route matches [GET] "/"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, devise

Title: "undefined method 'devise_for' error after installing and configuring Devise gem"

I installed the Devise gem by adding `gem 'devise'` to my Gemfile and running `bundle install`. I also ran `rails generate devise:install`, added `config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }` to `config/environments/development.rb`, and added `<p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>` and `<p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>` to `app/views/layout/application.html.erb`.

I then generated a `User` model using `rails generate devise User` and ran `rake db:migrate`. However, when I tried to access the page, I saw the error "No route matches [GET] /".

When I commented out the line `devise_for :users` or placed it at the end of `config/routes.rb`, I could see the page but `/users/sign_in` didn't work and I saw the error `undefined method 'devise_for'`.

Here is my current `config/routes.rb` file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: "hello#index"
  devise_for :users
end
```

How can I fix this error and get the Devise authentication routes working correctly?

Comment: Does your `User` class include the `devise` modules?

Comment: Sounds like `devise` isn't initialized yet. Check out your initializer files and make sure there's one for `devise` and that you've reviewed it.

Answer (score 1):

I had something similar occur. The key thing to remember is to restart Rails after you have installed and set up the model and views for devise.